# pass multiple objects to RequestContext in django

Tags: django, django-views, requestcontext

I need to pass a dict and an object to a template. So, I do this

```
rc = RequestContext(request, {'prob':prob}, {'result':result})
return render_to_response('subject/question.html', context_instance=rc)
```

But I get a error.

```
Traceback: File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.  response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "E:\django-sample\proschools\..\proschools\subject\views.py" in eval_c
  72.   rc = RequestContext(request, {'prob':prob}, {'result':result}) File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py" in __init__
  173.  self.update(processor(request))

Exception Type: TypeError at /practice/c/eval/ 
Exception Value: 'str' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
rc = RequestContext(request, {'prob':prob, 'result':result})
```

3rd parameter is `processors` that should be tuple or list

Answer (score 9):

You can also use the [`render` shortcut](http://django.me/render) which includes `RequestContext` and then just pass your variables normally.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def someview(request):
    return render(request,'subject/response.html',{'prob':prob,'result':result})
```

Comment: thanks. It's high time someone wrote a 'good' book on django.