# Django : Passing multiple objects to templates but nothing in there

Tags: python, django, object, web

I wanted to pass two objects to templates, so I put theme in the context and try to send them but failed.  I tried few times but it seems like user get objects but comment is always empty even though there are some data in db.

This is views.py

```
@login_required
def detail(request, article_no):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect_to_login(next, 'blog/login.html')
else:
    user = request.user

    if 'username' in request.session:
        username = request.session['username']
        item = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=article_no)
        item.hit = Article.objects.filter(pk=article_no).update(hit = item.hit+1)
        #comment = Comment.objects.filter(pk=article_no).order_by('comment_no')
        comment = Comment.objects.all()
        context = {
             'item': item,
             'comment': comment,
            }
    return render(request, 'blog/detail.html', context)
```

this is models.py

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import default

class Article(models.Model):
   no = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   content = models.CharField(max_length=300)
   writer = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   is_visible = models.BooleanField(default=True)
   created_date = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, default=datetime.now())
   hit = models.IntegerField(default=1)

class Comment(models.Model):
    article_no = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    comment_no = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    comment_writer = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    comment_body = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    comment_date = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, default=datetime.now())
```

template

```
         {{ item.title }}
         {{ item.no }}
         {{ item.writer }}
         {{ item.hit }}
         {{ item.created_date }}
         {{ item.content }}
 {% if comments %}

                {% for comment in comments %}

                {{ comment.comment_no }}
                {{ comment.comment_writer }}
                {{ comment.comment_body }}
                {{ comment.comment_date }}

                {% endfor %}

                {% else %}
                <div class="row">no comment.</div>
            {% endif %}
```

Comment: comment vs comments

Answer (score 3):

The variable you're passing from the view with all the comments in is called `comment`, for some reason. But in the template you try to iterate over `comments`, which doesn't exist. You should use consistent naming; it would make more sense to use `comments`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
@login_required
def detail(request, article_no):
if not request.user.is_authenticated():
    return redirect_to_login(next, 'blog/login.html')
else:
user = request.user

if 'username' in request.session:
    username = request.session['username']
    item = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=article_no)
    item.hit = Article.objects.filter(pk=article_no).update(hit = item.hit+1)
    #comment = Comment.objects.filter(pk=article_no).order_by('comment_no')
    comment = Comment.objects.all()
    context = {
         'item': item,
         'comment': comment,
        }
return render(request, 'blog/detail.html', context)
```

Correction Code -->

```
@login_required
def detail(request, article_no):
if not request.user.is_authenticated():
    return redirect_to_login(next, 'blog/login.html')
else:
user = request.user

if 'username' in request.session:
    username = request.session['username']
    item = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=article_no)
    item.hit = Article.objects.filter(pk=article_no).update(hit = item.hit+1)
    #comment = Comment.objects.filter(pk=article_no).order_by('comment_no')
    comment = Comment.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/detail.html', {'item':item, 
    'comment':comment})
```

Details will be found here ([pass multiple objects to RequestContext in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361056/pass-multiple-objects-to-requestcontext-in-django))

And in the template you use comments but in your code, there are no comments, rather then it is a comment.